# The new changes over a xib files doesnt overwrite the old when I reinstall the app, the old still appear

Tags: ios

I have this problem when I try to update a xib for an existing app.

My app is multilingual and uses `en_US`, `es_ES` and `pt_BR`. When I change a label, button, view, ... from a xbi, and afterwards try to reinstall (overwrite old app) the app, the new changes for the xib don't appear, the old data views still appear.

The question is, what can I do to fix this problem, do I have to speficify a flag in `InfoPlist` or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question and waiting to be helpful to someone.

The problem only occurs when I make a change in a xib file and then run the application on the emulator, apparently not replaced the new xib files and the emulator uses the old xib files. (xcode 4.3, iPad/iPhone emulator 4.3/5.0)

To solve the problem, every time I make a change in xib files, delete the application and run the emulator again. When I distribute the application, I only need to reinstall as it will overwrite the old xib files, and in my case, the database in the document directory is safe. I noticed this because when I distribute the application, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to just delete the application from the simulator (same as on the phone). That will remove all the old files and copy over the new ones.

You can also delete the files directory from the application folder `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[OS version]/Applications/[appGUID]/`, which will contain a folder with a UUID name for each app (open the folders to see which one belongs to your app).

Comment: Thanks for your time and your quick response. If I delete the application from simulator or device, everything is OK, but the problem is that the application uses a sqlite database that I don't want to delete because contains important data for the user, and every time I release a new version the database needs to be intact. So, I need to find a way to overwrite the modified xib files without delete the application.